# Ember dynamic segments without emberdata

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm struggling with the dynamic segments of routes. Here is my code

```
        App.Router.map(function(){
        this.resource('stuff', {path: '/stuff/:stuff_id'}, function() {
          this.route('make');
          this.route('edit');
          this.route('delete');
          this.route('history');
          });
        });

        App.StuffRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
            model: function(param) {
            },
        setupController: function (){
            },
            renderTemplate: function() {
            }
        });

       App.StuffView= Ember.View.extend({
         defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile(stuffTemplate)
       });

       App.StuffController = Ember.Controller.extend();
```

What should I put in the model of `StaffRoute` that I stop getting `No route matched the URL 'crisis'` errors? for `localhost/#stuff` and how can I set up properly the dynamic segment part? My only problem with the ember documentation is, that all the examples use ember-data that is not production ready and I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'/stuff/:stuff_id'` matches only `/stuff/something`, not `'/stuff'`.

Try to define separate resource:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
this.resource('stuffs', {path: '/stuff'});
this.resource('stuff', {path: '/stuff/:stuff_id'}, function() {
    // routes ...
});
```

or

```
App.Router.map(function(){
this.resource('stuffs', {path: '/stuff'}, function() {
    this.resource('stuff', {path: '/:stuff_id'}, function() {
        // routes ...
    });
});
```

and use `App.StuffsRoute`, `App.StuffsView` and `App.StuffsController` for this resource.

Answer (score 1):

Without ember-data you would typically put direct getJSON with jQuery inside the `model` method on the route. The `model` methods supports promises so you can reuse the jQuery promise.

For instance given the route to load a list of images for the `/images/tag` route using the Flickr api would be,

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('images', { path: '/images/:tag'});
});

App.ImagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    flickerAPI = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?';
    console.log('ImagesRoute.model', params);

    return jQuery.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
      tags: params.tag,
      tagmode: 'any',
      format: "json"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('loaded images', data);
      return data;
    })
    .then(null, function() { console.log('failed to load images'); });
  }
});
```

The corresponding controller can access/bind to the properties of the returned json automatically. Or you can alias a few computed properties.

```
App.ImagesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  images: function() {
    return this.get('model').items;
  }.property('controller'),
  title: function() {
    return this.get('model').title;
  }.property('images')
});
```

And then render it via handlebars using these properties.

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='images'>
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
{{#each image in images}}
  <img {{bindAttr src='image.media.m'}} />
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Here's a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/ofodid/1#/images/alps) that does this.